# Find text in unordered list and click on link within that list item

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

In a ruby script that uses watir, I'm trying to find text within an list item within an unordered list, then click on the link within that list item. In the sample below, I want to find "Apple" and have it click on the link that takes you to http://samplegrocerystore.com/tehnc34.

```
<div class="col-login">
<img class="logo" src="/images/hello.png" />
<h1 style="margin-top:15px;">Select Account</h1>
You have multiple accounts -- please select the one you would like to log in with.
<ul>
<li><h3>The Grocery Store</h3><h4>Chapter: Apple (#01)</h4>
<br/><strong><a href="http://samplegrocerystore.com/tehnc34">Login to this account</a></strong>
</li><li>
<h3>The Grocery Store</h3><h4>Chapter: Banana (#02)</h4>
<br/><strong><a href="http://samplegrocerystore.com/896ghv">Login to this account</a></strong>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So, is there anything you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are saying that you don't know the link href ahead of time?

Assuming you have opened the page in question using a `Watir::Browser` variable called `browser`:

Working off the unique text in the list item (Apple),

```
browser.li(:text, /Apple/).link(:text, 'Login to this account').click
```

should click the desired link.

Or if you do know the link href ahead of time, it is easier to use that:

```
browser.link(:href, 'http://samplegrocerystore.com/tehnc34').click
```

Either one should work, though if your web page is fairly complicated using a regex to find the word Apple might be slowish.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML, you can use the `find` method on a lists collection to locate the element with the specified text and then click on the link within the list element:

```
li = lists.find { |el| el.text.include? "Apple"}
li.a.click
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following in irb:

```
browser.h4(:text => /Apple/).links.count
browser.h4(:text => /Apple/).parent.links.count
browser.h4(:text => /Apple/).parent.parent.links.count
```

until you find your answer with just 1 link, then that's your immediate link following the 'Apple' text.  Then just call it like below:

```
browser.h4(:text => /Apple/).parent.link.click
```